# Writing a python function for raising irrational numbers to higher powers

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a function in python called compute(a,b,p,n) where a,b,n are integers and n>0 and p is prime, that outputs the tuple (x,y) (x,y being integers) such that

[image]

Note that the constraints of the problem state that you're not allowed to use any external libraries.

Now, I set about to solve this problem by writing a recursive function. To that end, let us assume that

[image]

But, we also have

[image]

Therefore, we have

[image]

Equating coefficients now yields

[image]

With

[image]

Now, making use of the equations in (1) and (2), we can write a simple and straightforward recursive python function as

```
def compute(a,b,p,n):
    
     if n==1:
        return  (a,b)

     if n>1:
        return (a*compute(a,b,p,n-1)[0]+b*p*compute(a,b,p,n-1)[1], b*compute(a,b,p,n-1)[0]+a*compute(a,b,p,n-1)[1])
```

This code works fine for small values of n, say upto 10, but for large values of n it is horribly inefficient. Is there some alternate way to approach this problem which works faster, or perhaps some way to optimize this code so that it runs faster?

Comment: Well for starters, **don't needlessly call `compute(a,b,p,n-1)` four times**. In general, recursion is slow, iteration will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest improvements in speed often come from choosing a different algorithm. That's the approach I'm taking here. Your current implementation works by reducing the exponent n by 1 on each iteration, which is (at best) linear in n. If you can find a way to cut n in half on each iteration, the complexity is reduced to O(log n). This is not only asymptotically faster, it greatly reduces the recursive stack requirements—you can handle much much larger exponents without causing stack overflows.

You can achieve a repeated halving solution for raising base B to the n<sup>th</sup> power by leveraging the mathematical identities B<sup>n</sup> = (B<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup> for n even, or B*(B<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup> for n odd. As stated above, this results in an algorithm with O(log n) computational complexity, yielding a significant improvement for large values of n.

For your particular problem, B = (a + b*sqrt(p)). B<sup>2</sup> evaluates to (a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>*p + 2ab*sqrt(p)), while multiplying (a + b*sqrt(p))(c + d*sqrt(p)) yields ((ac+bdp) + (ad+bc)sqrt(p)). Using these results for the n even and n odd cases described above leads the following implementation in python:

```python
def compute(a,b,p,n):
    if n == 1: return (a,b)
    c, d = compute(a*a + b*b*p, 2*a*b, p, n // 2)
    if n % 2 == 0:     # n is even
        return (c, d)
    else:              # n is odd
        return (a*c + b*d*p, a*d + b*c)
```

In coding this I noticed that your base case is incorrect. The problem specification says that n is strictly greater than 0, so the base case should be `(a,b)` for `n == 1` since (a + b*sqrt(p))<sup>1</sup> = (a + b*sqrt(p)). If you want to include zero as a possible power, it would become `(1,0)` for `n == 0`. You can confirm that this is correct by making that change to your code and comparing the results to a hand-calculation of `compute(1, 2, 9, 2)`, i.e., a simple square of (1 + 2sqrt(9))<sup>2</sup> = 49 should be (37 + 4sqrt(9)) = 49. Your code currently produces (19 + 3sqrt(9)) = 28 but yields the correct answer when the base case is corrected as above.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I forgot to mention that 'p' is prime, I've fixed that in the question now.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I made some typos while writing this question, one of them being the base case of the code. I've fixed that now, nonetheless, thank you very much for pointing it out. It is well noted that your code runs much faster than the accepted answer, and much much faster than the abomination that I've written, but I hope you will forgive me for my ignorance in this regard, since I'm a complete beginner, and have only studied the big O notation in mathematical context and not in a programming context.

Answer (score 2):

The first optimization possibility is to only run `compute(a,b,p,n-1)` once per recursive call. then you would have

```
def compute(a,b,p,n):
    
     if n==1:
        return  (1,1)

     if n>1:
        recursive_compute = compute(a,b,p,n-1)
        return (a*recursive_compute[0]+b*p*recursive_compute[1], b*recursive_compute[0]+a*recursive_compute[1])
```

The second thing you could do is to drop recursion and iterate from 1 to n instead of from n to 1. Recursion in python is not tail call optimized, so your memory usage will increase after each recursive call.

This is one approach

```
def compute(a,b,p,n):
    current = (1,1)
    for _ in range(n -1):
        current = (a*current[0]+b*p*current[1], b*current[0]+a*current[1])
    return current
```

Since we don't grow the stack with recursion and don't allocate, this should be fast enough

Comment: as long as we are microoptimizing, use iterable unpacking, `x, y = 1, 1` then use `x, y = a*x + b*p*a, b * x + a*x`

Answer (score 2):

Happily, your equations are linear:

```
x_n = a x_(n-1) + b p x_(n-1)
y_n = b x_(n-1) +   a y_(n-1)
```

Let us rewrite these two scalar equations as a single matrix-vector equation:

```
X_n = M X_(n-1)

with:
  X_n = (x_n)    M = (a  bp)
        (y_n)        (b  a )
```

This recursive equation gives us a direct equation for X_n as a function of n:

```
X_n = M^(n-1) X_1
```

where `^` means "matrix exponentiation".

Now, if you had access to an external library, you could use that library's fast matrix exponentiation function. But since you don't, you'll have to write it yourself!

Fast matrix exponentiation is basically the same as fast scalar exponentiation: instead of multiplying `M` by itself `n` times, we're going to  use the fact that `M^(2k) = (M^k)^2` to cut down sharply on the number of matrix multiplications.

We end up with the following code:

```py
def matmul(A, B):
    return [[sum(A[j][i] * B[k][j] for j in range(2)) for i in range(2)] for k in range(2)]

def matvecmul(M, X):
    return [M[0][0]*X[0] + M[0][1]*X[1], M[1][0]*X[0] + M[1][1]*X[1]]

def matpow(M, n):
    if n == 1:
        return M
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        S = matpow(M, n//2)
        return matmul(S, S)
    else:
        S = matpow(M, n//2)
        return matmul(M, matmul(S, S))

def compute(a, b, p, n):
    Mn = matpow([[a, b*p], [b, a]], n-1)
    return matvecmul(Mn, [a,b])
```

Testing:

```py
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> import timeit
>>> start = timeit.default_timer(); x,y = compute(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, -1, 100000); stop = timeit.default_timer()
>>> stop - start       # execution time in seconds
0.00040509300015401095 # 0.4 millisecond
>>> x,y                # should be (1, 0) because (sqrt(2)/2 * (1 + sqrt(-1))) ** 100000 == exp(i pi/4)**(8*12500) == exp(i 2pi) == 1
(1.0000000000073506, 0.0)
```